# Why does cherry-pick include some unexpected commits?

Tags: git

I was trying to pick some specific commit by `git cherry-pick`, so before this unexpected behavior,
I thought that cherry-picks, based on the time of commits which they are submitted but after this event I don't know what's going on...

situation 1 graph:

```
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

the command I used:

```
git cherry-pick 79fa382..a1fde5a (head currently is pointing at c666151)
```

situation1 result:

```
 * gfkj56l e3(cherry-picked version of test1 branch)
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

in this scenario I thought the git picks the commits based on their time of creation in oldest to newest order so on this hypothesis, `e5` and `e3` should have been picked but we only have the `e3`...

in other example, we have:

situation2 graph:

```
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

the command I used:

```
git cherry-pick a1fde5a..db8fb8c (head currently is pointing at c666151)
```

situation2 result:

```
 * jdg98df e5(cherry-picked version of db8fb8c)
 * gfkj56l e4(cherry-picked version of 79fa382)
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

so in this scenario because e3 is newer than e5 I thought it shouldn't work but surprisingly it worked and I assumed it is picking the commits based on their topo order and it was correct and it was working based on its topo order but why it didn't pick the commits in situation 1 based on their topo-order? so that's the contradiction.

situation3 graph:

```
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

the command I used:

```
git cherry-pick a1fde5a..14aed (head currently is pointing at c666151)
```

situation3 result:

```
 * qwjk56s Merged commit(cherry-picked version of 14aed05)
 * jdg98df e5(cherry-picked version of db8fb8c)
 * gfkj56l e4(cherry-picked version of 79fa382)
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

and this situation blew my mind, because there is a linear path between `a1fde5a` and `14aed` , I wonder why it's picking e4 and e5?

and this issue applies to git revert and git log and so on. so git has a logic for working with range of commits, but I can't figure it out, so I wonder what's the logic?

Comment: Just in case.... ah, no..... when you say `git cherry-pick A..B`, git will _select_ commits that are in the history of `B` that are _not_ in the history if `A`... in the order that they are in the branch, regardless of time when they were authored.... or even committed (that information can be set at will because of git's flexibility).... so, it would _only_ cherry-pick `a1fde5a`, just as it did.

Comment: You are right, it works (requesting the cherry-pick, that is... that's why I deleted the comment where I said I would be surprised.... and I am... but it makes sense, actually).

Comment: For all your scenarios, the explanation is always the same: `A..B`, discard all commits from `A`, apply commits in `B`.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation about how to specify revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions)? The notation [`x..y`](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltrev1gtltrev2gtem) is described there and it does not mean what you think it means. The author or commit time is irrelevant, all that matters are the connections between commits (reachability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`r1..r2`](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation) means "*reachable* from r1, but *not reachable* from r2". It is equivalent to `^r1 r2`. Given your graph:

```
 * c666151 e6
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

- `79fa382..a1fde5a` only includes `a1fde5a`. (`05e10f7` is reachable from `79fa382`, thus excluded)
- `a1fde5a..db8fb8c` includes `db8fb8c` and `79fa382`. (`05e10f7` is reachable from `a1fde5a`, thus excluded)
- `a1fde5a..14aed` includes `14aed`, `db8fb8c`, and `79fa382`. (They *are* reachable from `14aed`)

`r1..r2` does *not* mean "the shortest path between those commits".

Only the "parent" relations between commits are relevant when computing commit ranges, the commit and author timestamps are completely irrelevant and ignored.

---

Expanding on the last example (`a1fde5a..14aed`):

```
 * 14aed05 Merged commit
 |\
 | * db8fb8c e5
 | * 79fa382 e4
 * | a1fde5a e3 (test1)
 |/
 * 05e10f7 e2
```

We can ask the following questions:

- Which commits are reachable from `14aed`? Answer: `14aed05` (the commit itself), `a1fde5a` (first parent), `db8fb8c` (second parent), `79fa382` (first parent of second parent), and `05e10f7` (eventually through both parents).
- Which commits are reachable from `a1fde5a`? Answer: `a1fde5a` (the commit itself) and `05e10f7` (the commit's only parent)

If you consider the commits from each answer as a "set of commits" and you subtract one from the other, that leaves you with the commits "reachable from r1, but not reachable from r2":

```
  { 14aed05, a1fde5a, db8fb8c, 79fa382, 05e10f7 }
- {          a1fde5a,                   05e10f7 }
= { 14aed05,          db8fb8c, 79fa382 }
```

The merge commit itself doesn't have any "changes" (compared to both its parents), so it does not create a new commit when cherry-picked.

Comment: I can't understand why in third situation why we don't have only `14aed` ( and it is acceptable based on your logic). @knittl

Comment: @teo77 because they are reachable from `14aed`. `X..Y` does not mean "the shortest path between those commits", but "reachable from Y, not reachable from X".

Comment: so if there was a commit between `a1fde5a` and `14aed`, so will it be cherrypicked alongside the `db8fb8c` and `79fa382` and if yes, what's their order....? @knittl

Comment: @teo77 yes, it will be included and cherry-picked together with the other two commits. The order? I don't know, it makes sense to use the author or committer date, but I don't know if it is specified in this case. I wouldn't be surprised if it is "first parent, then second parent".

Comment: another question wise man :D, I realized how this `X..Y` works but  where is the ending point? I mean git follows the `Y` history, simultaneously it follows the `X` history , so where is  the ending point for comparing `X` and `Y` history paths and consider the commits which is only considerable from  `Y`, I think the answer is the mutual commit between these two commits history? am I correct? @knittl

Comment: @teo77 there can be multiple ending points. These might be the commits that are reachable from both, or if that's not the case, the root commit(s) of your repository.